# Restrict Parse.com Query only to a User Session

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform

trying to build an Android and Web client that has Parse.com as a backend. User has to be authenticated first to log into the app. If someone gets hold of the Application keys, client keys etc. he can access the app without the authentication with Rest calls. How can this be avoided to restrict the Parse Query to return results ONLY with a user session? Looking for that security measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Parse Application and client keys (except for the master key) are considered **public information** and NOT secrets. This is clearly mentioned in the Parse documentation. There is no way to hide them and they will be part of your app/website and they can be easily retrieved by any user. This means any data in your classes with Public read access can be retrieved by anybody.

Parse lets you control the data read permissions **ONLY** via *Class Level Permissions(CLPs)* and *Access Control Lists(ACLs)*. If you think these solutions cannot give you the security measures you are looking to implement, you have to disable the public read access to your data completely and implement your own `Cloud Functions` to retrieve the data from server. This way, you can test the user credentials, permissions, etc before returning any data.